# How to add data to excel worksheet from 2 different forms in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a vb.net project that puts data to excel workbook. I have two Windows forms. The 1st is adding data successfully to worksheet(1), but I can't add data from the 2nd Windows form (textboxes) to worksheet(2).

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: 'in FORM2
Public Class saisiephen

    Dim app As Excel.Application
    Dim crq As Excel.Workbook
    Dim hrly As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim phen As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim extr As Excel.Worksheet


 Private Sub btnphvalid_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnphvalid.Click

        app = New Excel.Application
        crq = app.ActiveWorkbook
        crq.Worksheets(2).Cells(2, 2).Value = txtcode.Text

    End Sub

Comment: when the application run an exl app is running.form1 add to WKS1 and form2 may add to WKS2 some data from txtboxes.

Comment: Please, edit your answer and add the relevant code there.